# Field filter does not Work for Text Formula field used in SOQL

Tags: apex, soql, formula, formula-field

I have a simple SOQL query on Account which has a field Full_Address__c which is joint of Billing Street, City Zip.

When I use this field as a filter it doesn't return the records:

Example:

```
String accountAddress = [SELECT Full_Address__c FROM Account LIMIT 1].Full_Address__c;
System.debug('accountAddress '+accountAddress);
Account acc = [SELECT id, Full_Address__c FROM Account where Full_Address__c =:accountAddress LIMIT 1];
```

Returns:

[image]

It means that the same value I am getting by query doesn't work as filter. Looks like a bug.

Formula:

```
ShippingStreet & BR() & 
ShippingCity & ", " & ShippingState & " " & ShippingPostalCode & BR() & 
ShippingCountry
```

Comment: I have noticed this previously. Currently this is not allow in salesforce. vote up for this idea https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BpzQAAS

Comment: This is different than the Idea link given. Here is no formula SOQL. Its simple field join or concatenation of 4 fields.

Comment: Ahh looks like misread it  :-)

Comment: I think its issue with BR() function. When i removed it from the formula it worked just fine.

For ex: 

    ShippingStreet & ", " &ShippingCity & ", " & ShippingState & " " & ShippingPostalCode & ", " & ShippingCountry

Comment: What if the Account you queried doesn't have the values filled in, hence why it comes back null. When you look at the field in a report or page layout is it populated? Then are you querying for that record that is populated?

Comment: I was able to reproduce, fwiw.

Comment: @DanWooding Did you notice a system.debug in given code? It wasn't null.

Comment: You mean @AdrianLarson?

Answer (score 0):

Use String method escapecsv() to hanldle the New line character you are inducing in the formula field.

```
  String accountAddress = String.escapeCsv([SELECT Full_Address__c FROM Account LIMIT  1].Full_Address__c);
  System.debug('accountAddress '+accountAddress);
  Account acc = [SELECT id, Full_Address__c FROM Account where Full_Address__c =:accountAddress LIMIT 1];
```

Comment: Did you try this code yourself?

Answer (score 0):

Just pass the particular `record ID` on url like
Example: `https://salesforce.com/pagename?id=175433#175433`
Then you will get the Particular record values.

```
String accountAddress = [SELECT Full_Address__c FROM Account LIMIT 1].Full_Address__c;
System.debug('accountAddress '+accountAddress);
Account acc = [SELECT id, Full_Address__c FROM Account where Full_Address__c =:accountAddress LIMIT 1];
System.debug('acc '+acc);
```